# There isn't QStateMachine framework in Qt6.6

Tags: qt, qt6

As the title, I can't find QStateMachine...

I have newly installed Qt Creator 12.01. I'm using Qt6.6.1.

Why?

`#include <QStateMachine>` emits warnings although I wrote necessary things into CMakeList.txt.

What did I mistake?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(myProjectName VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS StateMachine Widgets )
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)

set(PROJECT_SOURCES
        main.cpp
        Widget.cpp
        Widget.h
)

if(${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} GREATER_EQUAL 6)
    qt_add_executable(myProjectName
        MANUAL_FINALIZATION
        ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        ...
    )
# Define target properties for Android with Qt 6 as:
#    set_property(TARGET myProjectName APPEND PROPERTY QT_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR
#                 ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android)
# For more information, see https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt-add-executable.html#target-creation
else()
    if(ANDROID)
        add_library(myProjectName SHARED
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
# Define properties for Android with Qt 5 after find_package() calls as:
#    set(ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android")
    else()
        add_executable(myProjectName
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
    endif()
endif()

target_link_libraries(myProjectName PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets Qt6::StateMachine)


# Qt for iOS sets MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER automatically since Qt 6.1.
# If you are developing for iOS or macOS you should consider setting an
# explicit, fixed bundle identifier manually though.
if(${QT_VERSION} VERSION_LESS 6.1.0)
  set(BUNDLE_ID_OPTION MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER com.example.myProjectName)
endif()
set_target_properties(myProjectName PROPERTIES
    ${BUNDLE_ID_OPTION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)

include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(TARGETS myProjectName
    BUNDLE DESTINATION .
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
)

if(QT_VERSION_MAJOR EQUAL 6)
    qt_finalize_executable(myProjectName)
endif()
```

At the place of Qt6::StateMachine , warning is emit.

Comment: You did not read the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstatemachine.html) which clearly states what to do when you want to use QStateMachine: `CMake: find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS StateMachine)
target_link_libraries(mytarget PRIVATE Qt6::StateMachine)`

Comment: @chehrlic I had already tried that. But warning is emit. I try to reinstall Qt6... By the way, are you able to include QStateMachine on the same environment?

Comment: No need to reinstall Qt - when you do it correct then it will work. Please post your CMakeLists.txt

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem.

Simply, I didn't install additional components.

[image]